# Type cast vs type assertion on concrete struct?

Tags: casting, go

I am new to golang, so appologize if this question is too naive. Looked around, but could not find answer to my basic question.

Lets say I have a concrete struct and methods as shown below.

```
 type MyData struct{
     field1 string
     field2 int 
     }

func(a MyData) OperatorOnString() string{
  return a.field1.(string)
}

func(a MyData) OperatorOnInt() int{
  return a.field2.(int)
}
```

My question is, can I type cast and return rather than performing assertion? From what I have learned so far is that, assertion is used on data of type interface. But in this case I have concrete type. Should I still use assertion or I can do something like `return int(a.field2)`. I know this example is trivial, but the point that I am confused is when to use between the two conversion types. Or is there some golang idiomaticity involved here?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) can be used only on interfaces:

> For an expression `x` of interface type and a type `T`, the primary expression

```
x.(T)
```

> asserts that `x` is not nil and that the value stored in `x` is of type `T`. The notation `x.(T)` is called a type assertion.

But you're applying it to non interface typed fields (`int` and `string`). That makes compiler [unhappy](http://play.golang.org/p/NjX0MRnukk).

Secondly, if you want to return type `T` from a method/function, it's always enough to return an expression of type `T`, which your fields already happen to be. The correct code is then easy:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyData struct {
        field1 string
        field2 int
}

func (a MyData) OperatorOnString() string {
        return a.field1
}

func (a MyData) OperatorOnInt() int {
        return a.field2
}

func main() {
        a := MyData{"foo", 42}
        fmt.Println(a.OperatorOnString(), a.OperatorOnInt())
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/bKx9zcWrjb)

---

Output:

```
foo 42
```

Comment: Thanks. However in real scenario, my operators will have some arguments which will be used to operate on MyData fields. Hence before returning that field, do I need to check the type?

Comment: @Minty: Show real code. Most probably you are mixing several concepts and it won't get better without real code.

Comment: @Minty: If a fn returns type `T` then only expressions of type `T` can appear in `return expr`. It's not about fields, it's about the type of the expression. E.g. if say we have `var i int` in a fn returning `int64` then we can and must write `return int64(i)`. Ad "to check the type": Type checking is done by the compiler for you automatically.